# Creating watch wallet from master public key at command line?

Tags: electrum, cli

I know that by `electrum -w WALLET_PATH create` a usual wallet can be created.  I'm now looking for way to create wallet file from master public key.

#### Question

- Given I have master master public key, e.g. `xpub12345...ABCDE`, how can I create its watching wallet file?

Comment: Also asked on https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/3822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
electrum -w wallet_path restore <mpk>
```

Above created watch wallet from master public key.